# Could not load type 'Facebook.FacebookApplication'

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I installed Facebook C# SDK using nuGet but I am getting this error:

Could not load type 'Facebook.FacebookApplication' from assembly 'Facebook, Version=6.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=58cb4f2111d1e6de'.

When I browsed the code using Reflector I couldnt find Facebook.FacebookApplication either.

Is this a bug? Has anyone else had an issue with Facebook C# SDK version 6?

Comment: I'd like to know this too, as I've been playing with the SDK for days and can't get anything working!

Comment: anyone has answered to this?

Answer (score 0):

I could never get the Facebook C# SDK to work until I created a website inside IIS and pointed the Physical Path to the folder containing the Facebook C# Example I wanted to run.

In my opinion, Facebook C# SDK needs to run inside IIS.

After setting up the new website inside IIS, you can go to Sites. Right click on your new website, then click on 'Manage Web Site', then click on Browse. This will open it on your browser.

Make sure your web.config file is crrectly configured or you'll get number errors (normally 500 Internal Server errors).